# want to show both correct and incorrect answer when the choosen answer is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Need to get the green background on the correct answer with the red background on the incorrect answer when we choose a wrong answer in the quiz. I need to show a pop-up that congratulate the user to complete this quiz. How is this possible ? I am new to JavaScript . Help me to find solution

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Quick Quiz - Play</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Main/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
      <div id="hud">
        <div id="hud-item">
          <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
            Question
          </p>
          <div id="progressBar">
            <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hud-item">
          <p class="hud-prefix">
            Score
          </p>
          <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
            0
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this questions?</h2>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="timer-quiz">Time left : <span id="timer"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <audio id="crctmusic" src="/Assets/win31.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio id="wrngmusic" src="/Assets/computerError.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.choice-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 6vw;
  border: 0.1rem solid rgb(86, 165, 235, 0.25);
  background-color: white;
  text-align: justify;
}

.choice-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgba(86, 185, 235, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
  transition: transform 150ms;
}

.choice-prefix {
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  background-color: #56a5eb;
  color: white;
}

.choice-text {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.correct {
  background-color: #28a745;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: #dc3545;
}

/* HUD */

#hud {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hud-prefix {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

.hud-main-text {
  text-align: center;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 0.3rem solid #56a5eb;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

#progressBarFull {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: #56a5eb;
  width: 0%;
}

/*TIMER*/
.timer-quiz {
  color: #efd0ca;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
  background-color: #56a5eb;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript

```
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
const progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
const scoreText = document.getElementById("score");
const progressBarFull = document.getElementById("progressBarFull");
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = false;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuesions = [];

let questions = [{
    question: "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript??",
    choice1: "<script>",
    choice2: "<javascript>",
    choice3: "<js>",
    choice4: "<scripting>",
    answer: 1
  },
  {
    question: "What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?",
    choice1: "<script href='xxx.js'>",
    choice2: "<script name='xxx.js'>",
    choice3: "<script src='xxx.js'>",
    choice4: "<script file='xxx.js'>",
    answer: 3
  },
  {
    question: " How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?",
    choice1: "msgBox('Hello World');",
    choice2: "alertBox('Hello World');",
    choice3: "msg('Hello World');",
    choice4: "alert('Hello World');",
    answer: 4
  }
];

//CONSTANTS
const CORRECT_BONUS = 1;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 50;

startGame = () => {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuesions = [...questions];
  getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
  if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
    //go to the end page
    return window.location.assign("/End/end.html");
  }
  questionCounter++;
  progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
  //Update the progress bar
  progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;

  const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuesions.length);
  currentQuestion = availableQuesions[questionIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

  choices.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset["number"];
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
  });

  availableQuesions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
  acceptingAnswers = true;
};

choices.forEach(choice => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

    const classToApply =
      selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

    if (classToApply === "correct") {
      incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
    }
    if (classToApply === "correct") {
      document.getElementById('crctmusic').play();
    } else {
      document.getElementById('wrngmusic').play();
    }

    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

    setTimeout(() => {
      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
      getNewQuestion();
    }, 1000);
  });
});

incrementScore = num => {
  score += num;
  scoreText.innerText = score;
};

startGame();
```

Comment: Off topic: *"What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script"* - none of the answers are correct - leave you to determine what it *should* be...

Comment: This question is too general. Please break it down into more specific questions and doubts.

Comment: @edo9k I need to show user the correct answer if user selected a wrong answer. How make it possible ?